# laravel 8 localhost ssl ecommerce payment gateway response FAILED TO CONNECT WITH SSLCOMMERZ API

Tags: php, laravel-8

Laravel 8 project local host connect ssl ecommerce payment gateway. But If i clcik pay now button not redirect to payment page . If i `dd( )` response then say FAILED TO CONNECT WITH SSLCOMMERZ API.

[image]

Now Give me solution how to redirect payment page